# Can I run mysqli functions, without upgrading PHP version5.4 to 7

Tags: php, mysqli, server

My requirement is bit odd... I have multiple doubts..

1. Could you please tell what are all the problems I'll face if I upgrade php5.4 to PHP 7? (on PHP 5.4 a process is already running, and I don't want to interrupt it)
2. Can I run mysqli functions, without upgrading PHP version5.4 to 7?

Comment: I was about to flag this as off topic, as I think it could get way better answers in server fault. I did not because of the PHP language part which has nothing to do with server admin. I suggest you go to server fault if you need more help with point #1

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can run. If your PHP version greater thank 5.3 you can run MysqLi. But I suggest you use PDO instead of MySqLi
For more information please check the URL : http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.installation.php

Comment: Why do you suggest PDO over MySQLi?

Comment: You  can use named parameters with PDO, and PDO's advantage is easier to move between different database types (e.g. if you want to work with Oracle or SQL Server or PostreSQL) it is easier to make the transition, and it is far more powerful if you like to work with classes. And of course I like OOP structure. I only suggest, I am not say you have to use this.

Answer (score 0):

1. Way to long to state here. You can follow this tutorial https://auth0.com/blog/migrating-a-php5-app-to-php7-part-one/
2. mysqli is available in PHP5, so it should be OK. If the app requires PHP7, there are ways to install it without affecting your current PHP5 install...
3. mysqli is available in PHP5

Comment: i  followed the above mentioned link three days ago, but they hadnt mentioned abt mysqli in php5.

Comment: No, that guide is to upgrade your PHP version, and has nothing about your actual code. You should check PHP's changelogs to make sure they did not remove functions you used, but generally they'd already throw a deprecated notice...